# idea2021/2020 maven project Process terminated without any error

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

output message:

```
D:\software\jdk8\bin\java.exe -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\Users\zoucheng\IdeaProjects\untitled3 -Dmaven.home=D:\software\maven-3.6.3 -Dclassworlds.conf=D:\software\maven-3.6.3\bin\m2.conf "-Dmaven.ext.class.path=E:\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven-event-listener.jar" "-javaagent:E:\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=49493:E:\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath D:\software\maven-3.6.3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar;D:\software\maven-3.6.3\boot\plexus-classworlds.license org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2021.1.3 -s D:\software\maven-3.6.3\conf\settings.xml -Dmaven.repo.local=E:\respository compile
```

[image]

[image]
There are no mistakes.I just used the built-in Maven to create an empty Maven project, and it went wrong.If anyone knows why, please let me know. Thank you very much.

Comment: How do you run it in IntelliJ IDEA? There should be build log. What do you see inside?

Comment: I click compile button of maven to run it. There isn't build log. I use cmd to build project and there is no problem.I'm very confused. I hope you can help me

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. The reason is that idea conflicts with another translation software of mine. This software is called 金山词霸.I shut down the software and it will run successfully.